# How to redirect to the same page after an action in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have this function `add_to_cart` once a product is added to cart it should redirect to the same.( since the the answers have not solved the issue ).
I have changed at least should redirect to product detail page requires to pass an argument either slug or product id any idea

```
def add_to_cart(request, **kwargs):
    ------------------------
    ------------------------
    messages.info(request, "item added to cart")
    return redirect(reverse('products:single_product',args=(request)))
```

url for product detail

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/$',single, name="single_product"),
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Is there anything wrong with your current approach?

Comment: yeah wanted it to redirect on the same page not the product list page ,just assume someone added the product to cart on the home page

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```py
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

You can also read about how Request/Response works in Django but also about the `request.path_info` in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path_info)

Comment: @Cipher I edited my answer and added a link to the docs so you can read about the `request.path_info`

Answer (score 3):

You can use request.path to find the current url of the request and then redirect.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect(request.path)
```

Comment: what is this path thing ( is something like product.id or slug )

Comment: It is an attribute of the request that has the information that tells us which url did the user call this request from... .path_info also serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Send the address where you are calling from in kwargs and redirect to that.

Comment: an example please

Answer (score 0):

[HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/)

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

Comment: what do you mean path_info,

Comment: You could always use path instead of path_info. but as it is pointed out in the documentation I linked path_info always contains the path info portion of the path, no matter what Web server is being used.

Comment: path works but still redirects to the same product list page

Comment: do you want to redirect to the cart page or product list page? because the code I posted will redirect you to the page you were in. so where do you exactly want to redirect?

Comment: It is perfect just for the product list  page my question: lets say am on the product detail page and there is a button to add to cart after adding to cart i need to remain on the same page not being redirected to another page  hope its clear

Answer (score 0):

Use **"request.path"** to get **the current url** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    return redirect(request.path) # Here
```

Or, use **"request.path_info"** to get **the current url** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    return redirect(request.path_info) # Here
```